# Shortest time between grand slam walk offs

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, records, home-run

Steve Pearce of Toronto Blue Jays hit game winning grand slam walk offs on July 27th and 30th 2017 against Oakland Athletics and Los Angeles Angels respectively.

With a 3 days span between Pearce's slams, is this the shortest time between 2 grand slam walk offs in MLB history? If not who has this record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, because [Steve Pearce became the first player in MLB history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Pearce_(baseball)#Toronto_Blue_Jays) to hit multiple walk-off grand slams within the span of a single week.